# Ionic Printer it does not print a single element

Tags: ionic-framework, printing

Hi guys i have this problem when i try to print an html item, but it also dispenses the whole page adding a call id does not function this is my code:

**.html**

```
<ion-row >
  <ion-item *ngFor="let order of orders" id="pdf" >
      <ion-icon name="mail-open" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      
      <p>  ordine:  {{  order.id}}</p>
      <p class="prob">  Indirizzo: {{ order.billing.address_1}} <br> Città:  {{ order.billing.city}}   
          <br> Numero: {{ order.billing.phone}}</p>
      <p class="prob"> Nome:  <br>  {{ order.billing.first_name}}  {{ order.billing.last_name}}</p>

      <button type="button" mat-button color="primary" (click)="printDocument()"></button>
          </ion-item>
 </ion-row>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Printer, PrintOptions } from '@ionic-native/printer/ngx';


printDocument() {
  
 

     let options: PrintOptions = {
      name: 'MyDocument',
       duplex: true,
       };
          let content = document.getElementById('pdf');
          this.printer.print(content, options);
      
       }
```

and that's what happens:

[print all page not a single item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idxmH.png)